# Representing polynomial in terms of other polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Does there any theorem with algorithm which says,  any polynomial $P$ and $Q$ with common variable then $P$ can be represented in terms of $Q$ as
$$P=\sum_{i\in S}P_iQ^i$$ and there exists unique polynomials $P_i$ have same degree for all $i$ and $S\subset\mathbb{Z}$.

For example:
Sum of cube of first natural number is square of sum of first natural number that is

$P(n) =  \sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ and $Q(n)= \sum_{k=1}^n k$ and $P(n)= 1\cdot Q^2(n)+0\cdot Q(n)+\ldots$

*I'm not taking about polynomial division algorithm*. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think $P=x$ can be represented in terms of powers of $Q=x^2$... Or do you mean $P_0 = x^2$? Question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Do you allow the case where $\,S=\{0\}$?

Comment: @Somos yes, if $deg(Q)>deg(P)$ then $S=\{0\}$ only option will be there

Comment: @OleksandrKulkov if $P=x$ and $Q=x^2$ then $P=P_0$ because $deg(Q)>deg(P)$

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want that $\deg P_i < \deg Q$, the existence of such representation indeed follows from the fact that polynomials over any field form  a Euclidean domain, that is, we can uniquely represent

$$
P(x) = P_0(x) + D_1(x) Q(x),
$$

where $\deg P_0 < \deg Q$. Then, we can in turn represent

$$
D_1(x) = P_1(x) + D_2(x) Q(x),
$$

where $\deg P_1 < \deg Q$, and so on, so you can find $P_0, P_1, \dots$ with consecutive division by $Q$ and taking remainders. Note that, generally, $\deg D_k = \deg P - k \deg Q$, so it will get down to $D_k = 0$ eventually.

Comment: Is this the only way (know so far) to represent a polynomial in terms of another polynomial

Comment: Yes, it is unique, as remainders and long division result are unique.